# The equivalent of a maven "promote" goal

Tags: maven, deployment

Is there an equivalent to a mvn

**"deploy:promote"**

goal, which will take an artifact from one repository and copy it to another ?

I call this **"promote"**  because the **typical use case would be promotion of a snapshot to a release.**

I know that proprietary tools exist with UI's for doing this sort of thing.... But I'm assuming that the *deploy plugin would handle it as well.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot promote a snapshot to a release.

An snapshot has a version like 1-SNAPSHOT(.complextimestamp)

That version number is in your pom. It's in the metadata in META-INF in your jar or war file. So you can't just copy the artifact and declare that it has a different version.

You must rebuild with the release version and deploy that. The maven-release-plugin and the jgitflow-maven-plugin both automate this process.